# bounding box - generate coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, spatial-database, extents, mongodb

I will be using mongodb database which supports data on an **Euclidean plane** (not spherical). I will be performing queries which return all points within a box.

For the box I need to specify the upper left and bottom right coordinates (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/box/#op._S_box).

My question is based on an a lat/long coordinate as input, how can I create these two coordinates needed?

I want to take my coordiante and create a box of roughly ~1km (I understand since it is a box it will not be 1km in all directions, but I am not looking for perfect accuracy).

Is there an algorithm for this?

Comment: May I ask why you need to use bbox query?  BBox searching would general be utilised when you already have the bottom left and upper right coordinates available to you, i.e. a box has been drawn.  Constructing a box around a centre point using lat/long coordinates is non trivial with Mongodb in comparison to the other proximity queries offered (e.g. near).

Comment: what other languages/frameworks are you using other than Mongodb?

Comment: I am also using Java.

Comment: do you have any further background to your requirement?

Comment: @Guy I am essentially getting a geolocation input in my java servlet. Once I have the location I need to calculate the bounding box corners and attach them to my boubsing box query and send that query to mongodb.

Comment: and why a bbox query rather than a radius search?  Is the result then being visualised somehow?

Comment: For performance issues. Radius was slow on mongodb compared to bbox

Comment: As well near is not supported when sharding